# Spring Boot: class with @Service bean bean not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have multiple `@Service` class which implements a class `BaseService`

In a `Controller` class,
I want to call a `Service` class (which implements `BaseService`) based on a parameter

I'm using a function in `Utils` and calling it from the `Controller` class

```
public final class Util {
   
   public static BaseService getService(String num){
     AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
     context.refresh();
     if(num == 1){
        return context.getBean(TestService.class);
    }
      return context.getBean(AnotherService.class);
   }
}
```

My `TestService` class has an `@Service` annotation

`TestService` works if I call it using constructor in the `Controller` class

```
@Autowired
public TestController(TestService service){
   this.service = service;
}


service.callMethod(); //This works!!
```

But if I call the instance using `Util` class, it gives me `No such bean as TestService available`

Comment: Why would you create the context yourself and refresh it, that makes no sense?

Comment: Would it not be easier to have all the beans injected, and then make the call on the appropriate instance?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The refresh was added because it gave me an error "Context is not refreshed yet" before this

Comment: @MichaelPiefel How can I structure that?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘structure that’? You know how to inject `TestService`. Just have `AnotherService` injected as well, to another field.

Comment: The `Util` class could have injected all the beans extending from `BaseService`. Then passing a parameter, you could return the already injected bean. If you still want to so something like in your snippet, I would try implementing the `ApplicationContextAware` interface to get access to the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is initially empty. To quote the documentation: “Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext that needs to be populated through `register(java.lang.Class<?>...)` calls and then manually refreshed.”

Comment: Is there any alternative for `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` ?

Comment: You can implement `ApplicationContextAware` for instance, and have Spring’s context injected instead of creating your own.